# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact error when using RAD 9.1

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

I am using RAD 9.1 and have a maven project which has an EAR and WAR project. The pom.xml in the EAR file is giving errors as below.

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact com.CNSBCB:MemberBillingPayment:pom:${release.version} from/to apache-snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/): Illegal character in path at index 72: http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/com/cnsbcb/MemberBillingPayment/${release.version}/MemberBillingPayment-${release.version}.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

This is how my pom.xml is :
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    MemberBillingPaymentEAR
    ear

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.CNSBCB</groupId>
    <artifactId>MemberBillingPayment</artifactId>
    <version>${release.version}</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>


<build>
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo>Creating aatprop file: </echo>
                            <echo file="${basedir}\src\main\application\${aatp.v}.aatprop"> ${aatp.v} </echo> 
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>    
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.CNSBCB</groupId>
                        <artifactId>MemberBillingPaymentWAR</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>MemberBillingPaymentWAR.war</bundleFileName>
                        <contextRoot>/MemberBillingPaymentWeb</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
                <displayName>MemberBillingPaymentEAR.ear</displayName>
                <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
                <!--<applicationXml>MemberBillingPaymentEAR/src/main/application/META-INF/application.xml</applicationXml>-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.CNSBCB</groupId>
        <artifactId>MemberBillingPaymentWAR</artifactId>
        <version>${release.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>CNSBCB</id>
        <url>http://nexus.CNSBCB.com/content/repositories/CNSBCB</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

MemberBillingPaymentEAR and MemberBillingPaymentWAR is the name of the projects that I have. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `<version>` tag in the below piece of code

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.CNSBCB</groupId>
    <artifactId>MemberBillingPayment</artifactId>
    <version>${release.version}</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

In your you pom, you have not declared a variable/property with the name `release.version`. Hence it is not able to resolve/inherit the parent artifact.
In order to fix it, specify a valid version (For eg: 1.1.0) instead of specifying `${release.version}` in the `<version>` tag.